# Cannot create Windows password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a virtual machine on a Windows server on Compute Engine on Google Cloud. I try to set user and when I press create it loads forever and never generates a password.

Here is the Compute Engine I am trying to set up:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first create the Windows instance there is a delay between the time it spins up and becomes accessible. You can check the Serial Port (console) output to view the progress of the instance.

You can only create a username and password for Windows once the startup and activation has completed. This can take several minutes and the OS will restart a couple of times before it is fully ready to be used.

You can check the status of the OS through the serial port (console) output by clicking on your instance (Compute Engine > VM instances > your instance) and click on "Serial port 1 (console)" just below the graph.